# How to Use Geopoint?

Tags: android, android-mapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good way of getting the user's location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android)

I'm using a map view in my app but how can I get the user geopoint so I can set it as my default location using map view?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials on google that would help u do that!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html