# How to get current coordinates in using GoogleMaps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location

i want to get current coordinates, i try next

```
GoogleMap gm=getMap();
gm.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
Location location=getMap().getMyLocation();
```

But getMap() returns null, 
 and i try :

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if (location.getLatitude()!=0){
LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),           location.getLongitude());
```

But this work's in Android 2.3, but in 4.2. it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same code in my app and it works well on version 4 :

```
String provider;
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) 
                              getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

if (location != null) {
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
   mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

But your problem must be related to your getMap() error. What exactly is the error message ?

Comment: getLastKnownLocation(provider) this is not the best idea, i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The location properties are reset when the phone is rebooted.

So if the device hasn't requested a new location by any means(Maps or any other apps that request a location), getMyLocation will return null.

What you should do, if getMyLocation returns null, is to request a new Location.

Here is a thread on how to get/request a location: 
[Good way of getting the user's location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android)

Look for the `requestLocationUpdates()` method.

Then when a location has been found(It can take some time...especially indoor), the callBack OnLocationChanged is called with the new location in parameter.

Hope this helps!