# GPS data on android phone

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am building an app which can detect location change by reading GPS data. I am observing the change on longitude and latitude to detect the location change. But my app is only working when I go far away. The value I get on latitude and longitude is only upto two decimal points.Is there any way to get more precise data of latitude and longitude in android? I want get the value upto 7 or 8 decimal point. My code is given below-

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    Log.d("GPS ", "ON");
                    mysample = mysample + "GPS = 1 \n";

                    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    double latitude = 0;
                    double longitude = 0;

                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }

                    if ( plat != latitude || plong != longitude) {
                        Log.d("GPS MOVING ", "ON");
                        mysample = mysample + "GPS MOVING = 1 \n";
                        Log.d("GPS CORDINATE ", "" + longitude + "" + latitude);
                        plat = latitude;
                        plong = longitude;
                    } else {
                        Log.d("GPS MOVING ", "OFF");
                        mysample = mysample + "GPS MOVING = 0 \n";
                        Log.d("GPS CORDINATE ", "" + longitude + "" + latitude);

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d("GPS ", "OFF");
                    mysample = mysample + "GPS = 0 \n";
                    Log.d("GPS MOVING ", "OFF");
                    mysample = mysample + "GPS MOVING = 0 \n";
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting precise data of latitude and longitude is a nice idea however, setting location results to 7 or 8 decimal points is practically used in surveying purposes, as shown in [Decimal degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) in Wikipedia.

A perfect explanation for this concern can be found in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude).

Also, please check solution given in this SO post - [How to better handle GPS location and android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22338010). Hope it helps!