# Android GPS incorrect location data on query

Tags: java, android, gps

I am not using mock locations for this... In fact the code was working fine just last week.

I have an app that gathers GPS data and spits out a google maps link using X,Y coordinates generated by the application itself. I am not 100% sure why its not working the way it should be but when I request the app to make a google maps link based on the GPS location provided by the phone it tells me I am 5 - 6 blocks away from my point of origin (Where I actually am at the time) Not quite what I want it to do

Knowns:

- I have the proper permissions set up
- All of the code worked last week just fine

Here is the code to gather the GPS info:

```
        Toast.makeText(context, "Gathering GPS Data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    gps = new gpsTracker(Settings.this);
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        try{
            gps.getLocation();
            lon = gps.getLongitude();
            lat = gps.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your location is - \nlat: " + lat + "\nlon: " + lon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception  e){}
    }
    else{
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
```

The class all of the above is pulling from:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class gpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public gpsTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: gpsTracker is not a standard android class.  Without the code for it, there's no way to know what's going wrong.  My guess is you're either using a stale location or network provider where you don't have an accurate lock, but its pure guess without code.

Comment: I'll add that new class / location listener... Sorry that was my derp there. @GabeSechan - Just added now.

Comment: So about what I guessed.  You're calling getLastKnownLocation, so it may return a stale location, that could easily be a few blocks away-  or a location from the network provider which can be off by a few blocks while locking on.

Comment: @GabeSechan So, get rid of that and it should work again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what is specified[difference of 4-5 blocks], you may be  obtaining the `location` from `networkProvider` only.

With this `gpsTracker` code mentioned in the question,
there are a few modifications required, instead of using the code as it is:

***1.***
There are 2 `if` loops which verify the source of `location` is enabled or not and No '`else`':

```
 if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This means the application is going to do twice the work when you can obtain the `location` from both sources. Further, the source of `location` obtained always remains ambiguous.

This is good when you just need approximate `location` which should not be null majorly.

If you want to use only this class to obtain `location`, try structuring the `if-else` according to requirement and ensuring that its not going to repeat if the `location` is obtained.
***Eg.*** if `GPS` is on a higher preference, applies in your case, shift that `if` above and put the network condition with an `else` like:

```
if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            Log.d("Network", "Network");
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        }
```

For your requirement, i suggest removing the network provider part and obtaining the `location` only from GPS, esp if line of sight is not a problem.

When your code was working fine, it must be fetching the location from GPS and setting it in the object. But because of the two "`if`" and no "`else`", you'l never know whether `location` obtained is from Network or GPS - you can check [location.getProvider()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider()) inside the condition of `canGetLocation()`

***2.***
Also, you can log the message or prompt some action for one particular source...like:
In this part:

```
 if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        }
```

just separate it into two different `if`(s) and code accordingly. As of now, nothing happens here so you wouldn't know if both are disabled unless you check it externally.

*Suggestion: Try the [LocationClient which uses GooglePlayServices](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) for [Retrieving Current Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) . I have found it more reliable and useful. Check this [Fused Location Provider example](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html), setting [LocationRequest object](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html) according to your requirement is the key.*

Another update: just came across: [useful ques on stack overflow - Good way of getting the users location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android?rq=1)

---

**Update for anybody looking up this question/answer**
Regarding the suggestion of LocationClient;
LocationClient is no longer found under [`com.google.android.gms.location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html),  refer:
[Android play services 6.5: LocationClient is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372638/android-play-services-6-5-locationclient-is-missing)

Comment: Thank you kindly. I see what was going on. I feel like a bit of a derp for not figuring it out on my own but suffice to say I am glad I got this working!

Comment: Good you got it working, that is whats important. We miss things sometimes, that why there's [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html. There are some nice strategies to obtain accurate locations on this page. Here is some example code I've take from the site:

```
private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

/** Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current Location fix
  * @param location  The new Location that you want to evaluate
  * @param currentBestLocation  The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new one
  */
protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
    // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
      return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}
```