# Android LocationManager does not work in a specific activity

Tags: android, android-activity, location, locationmanager

I use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android) to get latitude and longitude. It works on my main activity, but not in an other activity of my project. Do you know why ? It's a fullscreen activity which use the device camera...

```
gpsTracker.latitude; //Always 0
```

Please ask me for more detail, but maybe one of you know the problem.

Comment: Is the other activity extending your main activity? check the context and if it is being passed to other activities...or is the code called statically....  
Also, please take a look at [this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962769/android-gps-incorrect-location-data-on-query) , esp if you are using gps tracker

Comment: It means that your device doesn't have a lastKnownLocation yet.  THat class isn't really good-  it hides some complexity, but does so poorly.  FOr example, there's no way to verify that a valid latitude or longitude exists, or if its giving possibly stale data.  I'd advise against using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments but the solution is to use

```
void android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action)
```

The class GPSTracker does not display the exception, I missed it :

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()