# How to store location co-ordinate every 2 minute in array in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I am just beginning to learn android, but could not get proper idea, how to handle this, so I want to store every 2 minute  location coordinate if i travel in bus.

What i am using:

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;
    TextView tv;
    ArrayList<String> cordsList= new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv=new TextView(this);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnShowLocation.setText("Start Save Location");
        Log.i("Finall", "AndroidGPSTrackingActivity-> ");
        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    String longlat=String.valueOf(latitude)+":"+String.valueOf(longitude);
                    cordsList.add(longlat);
                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

                Log.i("Finall", "Location-> "+cordsList.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

I am getting on time but could not get every 30 and where to store.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 2; // 2 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    10000,   // 3 sec
                    10, this);
            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();

                            Log.i("location", "->longitude>> "+longitude);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                  Log.i("location", "latitude->longitude>> "+latitude);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
         Log.i("latitude", "latitude-> "+latitude);
        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
         Log.i("longitude", "longitude-> "+latitude);
        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         Log.i("onLocationChanged", "onLocationChanged-> "+latitude+"---- "+longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i("onStatusChanged", "onLocationChanged-> "+latitude+"---- "+longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Hello , every body, any idea, If i travel bus and my gps on then i travel 20 minute, then i want to save 10 co-ordinate in arrays. Any idea, how to do this. and stop after clicking STOP button.

Thanks in Adavance.

Comment: your getLocation() method [could face this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962769/android-gps-incorrect-location-data-on-query/24074771#24074771), and ***to save the arrrays***, you can compare time or set interval for obtaining location and save lat, long which you get inside `onLocationChanged` in globally declared array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are can use the `Timer` class in android which will give you the `TIME_INTERVAL` to call that class .In your case you can  give the **TIME_INTERVAL = 20000**

Here is my example code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       Timer timer = new Timer();
       GpsTracker gpsTracker ;
       ArrayList<Double> arrLat= new ArrayList<Double>();
       ArrayList<Double> arrLng = new ArrayList<Double>();
       private final int TIME_INTERVAL = 20000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void run() {

            latitude = GPSTracker.getLatitude();
            longitude = GPSTracker.getLongitude();
            System.out.println("lat------ "+latitude);
            System.out.println("lng-------- "+longitude);

           arrLat.add(latitude);
           arrLng.add(longitude);

        }
    }, 0, TIME_INTERVAL);


  }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you it very helpful for me. but if i want to stop this coordinates in reading using stop button. any idea how to do this.

Comment: use timer.cancel() in stop button click listener.