# Sharing location from google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin android application which uses location. The application works fine most of the time.But Sometimes it shows a different location than my current location when taken using network providers and take more than 5 mins if using gps. At the same time google maps shows the correct location in an instant. How can i share that location from google maps to my application.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't say how do you get location, I assume that you used default `LocationManager` to get current location, did you distinguish the network for example like this?

```
locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

It's possible that you may check this case on SO: [Android GPS incorrect location data on query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962769/android-gps-incorrect-location-data-on-query).

For your question, you cannot directly get current location from google maps application, but you can use it's [api](https://enterprise.google.com/intl/en_sg/maps/products/mapsapi.html) to get it.

You may refer to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) to get started and to get the location, please refer to [Location Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location either from the mobile-network or from the GPS - In my experience The gps is the more accurate one to use.