# Background Service for geolocation is not working in Phonegap (android)

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am trying to get the location of device in a regular inteval of 10 or 20 seconds even in the the background. The background service is not working in android. I have followed the link

https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService/blob/master/2.9.0/README.md

I am using cordova 2.9.0.
My code is for background service is

```
var myService = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/myService');   
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {      
    getStatus();       
}
function handleSuccess(data) {
    updateView(data);
}

function handleError(data) {
    updateView(data);
}


function getStatus() 
{
    startService();
    myService.getStatus(function(r){handleSuccess(r)},
                        function(e){handleError(e)});
};

function startService() 
{
    myService.startService( function(r){handleSuccess(r)},
                                    function(e){handleError(e)});
}

function updateView(data) 
{
    var myVar;
    if (data.ServiceRunning) 
    {
        var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };   
        myVar = setInterval(function()
        {
            console.log("running");                    
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        }, 10000);
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}

function stopService() {
    myService.stopService(function(r){handleSuccess(r)},
                          function(e){handleError(e)});
}
```

In the onSuccess method i have saved the location in a file.
Now it is working fine with the app opening but not working in the background.

Comment: what is the purpose of putting this into background service?

Comment: i have to send the location details in every interval to FTP server to keep track of the record of the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you call geolocation from javascript code (in the function `updateView()`). The moment you put the application in the background, executing of javascript code will stop (and so will calling of `updateView()` function). The only thing working when the application is in background is the service you launched.

So what you probably want to do is alter native android code of `MyService` class and  call the geolocation inside service's `doWork()` function (something similar to what they did here, but instead of log you will do geolocation: https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService/blob/master/2.9.0/MyService.java):

```
public class MyService extends BackgroundService {
    ...
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doWork() {
        //geolocate and store the results to FTP using native java code
        return result;
    }   
    ...
```

If you don't know how to do geolocation in android native code, this post might be useful for you: [Good way of getting the user's location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android)