# Android Location Strategy

Tags: android, mobile, gps, location

In Android What are the location determination strategies for

1. Real-time GPS location determination (for user real-time user location tracking).
2. Periodic GPS location determination (for periodic user location determination).
3. For most accurate GPS location value.

I am trying to make mobile applications of type 1 and type 2. Please guide me regarding the same

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android/6280851#6280851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) API which is friendly and simple to use or `GPS` location API directly. Google Play Services API can return current user location or you can even subscribe to location updates. Take look official documentation.

Also there is not only `GPS`, but also mobile Network and Wi-Fi based location built in in Android. You can use all of them simultaneously thru FusedLocation provider to determine user location.

[Location APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)

[Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)