# Get current user location

Tags: java, android, android-location

I'm trying to get current user location but on some devices it works, but on some im stuck waiting for the location.

Here is my code:

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            // TODO
            Log.v("--", "get address 121");
            Main.this.location = location;
            getAddress();
            locationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("--", "provider enabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("--", "provider disabled");
        }
    };

    public void putExtra() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        intent.putExtra("timesobj", times);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Get current/last known location and display city, country name and update
     * calculations
     * */
    public void getAddress() {
        Log.v("--", "get address 1");
        boolean isGPSProviderEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean network_enabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.v("--", "get address 31 " + isGPSProviderEnabled + " gps  -  "
                + isConnectedToNetwork());

        if (isGPSProviderEnabled || network_enabled) {
            Log.v("--", "get address 2");
            Criteria c = new Criteria();
            Log.v("--", "provider " + locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true));
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager
                    .getBestProvider(c, false));

            if (location == null) {
                Log.v("--", "get address 6");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        locationManager.getBestProvider(c, false), 1000, 100,
                        mLocationListener);
            } else {
                Log.v("--", "get address 3");
                if (isConnectedToNetwork()) {
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            try {
                                com.myapp.utils.Geocoder geocoder = new com.myapp.utils.Geocoder(
                                        Main.this);
                                GeocoderModel geocoderModel = geocoder
                                        .getFromLocation(
                                                location.getLatitude(),
                                                location.getLongitude(), 5);
                                city = geocoderModel.getCity();
                                country = geocoderModel.getCountry();
                                prefs.edit().putString(Constants.CITY, city)
                                        .apply();
                                Log.v("--", "get address 4");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.v("--", "get address 11");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (LimitExceededException e) {
                                Log.v("--", "get address 12");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        };

                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            prefs.edit().putString(Constants.COUNTRY, country)
                                    .apply();
                            prefs.edit().putString(Constants.CITY, city)
                                    .apply();
                            populateList(location);
                        };
                    }.execute();
                } else {
                    city = prefs.getString(Constants.CITY,
                            getString(R.string.app_name));
                    Log.v("--", "get address 33 " + location.getLatitude());
                    populateList(location);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.v("--", "get address 5");
            startGpsEnableDialog();
        }
    }
```

and here is the Log that i have:

```
V/--      ( 5498): get address 1
V/--      ( 5498): get address 31 true gps  -  true
V/--      ( 5498): get address 2
V/--      ( 5498): provider gp
V/--      ( 5498): get address 6
```

Can someone help me what can be wrong in this code, and tell me how can I get the user location correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: probably those devices have not supported Gps

Comment: @koutuk i thins not, the problematic device is Nexus5

Comment: or it is because of week GPS sensor on those devices, and also i want to note that GPS is not working in all situations like indoor positions

Comment: `locationManager.getBestProvider(c, false)`-> you receive a disabled provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was adding this line of code:

```
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true), mLocationListener, Looper.myLooper());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the line

```
locationManager.getBestProvider(c, false)
```

to

```
locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true)
```

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider(android.location.Criteria,%20boolean)), "enabledOnly - if true then only a provider that is currently enabled is returned". You might get back a provider which is not enabled.

One more thing, you seem to be using Criteria, I usually not using it but from looking at your code it looks like you don't do much with it. I suggest you take another look at it. I found a code sample [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.location.Criteria) which might help you.

```
private void startLocationStuff(){
  locManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  locListener=new MyLocationListener();
  final Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
  criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
  criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
  criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
  criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
  criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
  bestProvider=locManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
}
```

You might want to consider using the Location manager without Criteria like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not that good and main too . Is there a better way .

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;

import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;

import android.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.IBinder;

import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by moodless3 2017
 */

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // Flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // Flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // Flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // Location
    double latitude; // Latitude
    double longitude; // Longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1000; // 1000 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 2; // 2 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {

        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {

        try {

            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

                // No network provider is enabled

            } else {

                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");

                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {

                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {

                    if (location == null) {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {

                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if (location != null) {

                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app.
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){

        if(locationManager != null) {

            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){

        if (location != null) {

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }


    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {

        if (location != null) {

            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog.
     * On pressing the Settings button it will launch Settings Options.
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing the Settings button.
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // On pressing the cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```