# Getting location updates both foreground and background in android google maps

Tags: android, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I am developing an android app which will track the user location trace (GPS Provider) and show polyline. I have implemented that using

> locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
>   0, 0, listener);

in my activity. But now when the user close the activity from the stack i can't get the location updates. Is it possible to get the location update even the activity closed?

Comment: You need to create `Service` for that...

Comment: @MD Is there any example available?

Comment: Search `GPS Logger in Android` and get source code from `Github`: [GPSLogger](https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good way of getting the user's location in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates

This is android developer source code for getting location updates.