# Displaying current location on a map

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-location, android-googleapiclient

The code that i wrote is supposed to show the location of the device on a map when the user opens the app.So i tried it on my phone and when i opened it i could see my location, however i walked about 2 km from that location and then opened the app again but my previous location was displayed on the map.

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fgps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my api key is here" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >     
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="AlarmReceiverActivity" android:label="@string/alarmReceiverActivity_string"></activity><activity
            android:name=".MnaActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.fgps.BackgroundLocationService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Activity:

```
package com.example.fgps;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
//,LocationListener 
{

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    //private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private String T_Text="";
    private double D_Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        if(mGoogleApiClient!= null){
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this,"Long press at the location you want to choose as your destination",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Create the LocationRequest object
        /*mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(6 * 1000)        // 4 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 500); // 1/2 second, in milliseconds
         */

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
            Intent i;@Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MnaActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("lat", point.latitude);
                i.putExtra("lng", point.longitude);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Setup");
                TextView text123 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                text123.setText("Enter title for alarm");
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                final EditText input2 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                input2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                lay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                lay.addView(text123);
                lay.addView(input);
                TextView text12 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                text12.setText("Enter raduis to start alarm\n(in Kms and above 200m)");
                lay.addView(text12);
                lay.addView(input2);
                builder.setView(lay);


                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        boolean flag=true;
                        T_Text = input.getText().toString();
                        try {
                            D_Text = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder2.setTitle("Error");
                            builder2.setMessage("Try again but check that title won't be empty\ndistance is above 200m=0.2km and written in NUMBERS");
                            builder2.show();
                            flag=false;
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if((T_Text.length()>0) && D_Text>=0.02)
                        {
                            i.putExtra("distance", D_Text);
                            i.putExtra("title", T_Text);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                            finish();
                        }else {
                            if(flag){
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder2.setTitle("Error");
                                builder2.setMessage("Try again but check that title won't be empty and distance is above 200m=0.2km");
                                builder2.show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();


            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    /*@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
    }
    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            /*if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }*/
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    /*private Marker oldMarker;
    private void setUpMap() {
        oldMarker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("activate gps!!"));
    }*/
    /*private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        oldMarker.remove();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        oldMarker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }
     */
    Location Mloc;
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        double currentLatitude=0;
        double currentLongitude=0;
        Mloc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        //Log.d(TAG, Mloc.toString());
        if(Mloc!= null)
        {
            currentLatitude = Mloc.getLatitude();
            currentLongitude = Mloc.getLongitude();
            //oldMarker.remove();
        }
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


        /*if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);*/
        /*}
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }*/
}
```

This activity isn't supposed to track me(getting location updates), it is supposed to show the location where i opened the app.
How can i solve this?

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the problem. First of all the GPS takes some time to initialize which might give you a null value during the first launch. Secondly you have to keep checking the GPS to make sure there's a location change.Fortunately after a long search I finally found an answer in Stack Overflow which gives the best/robust approach of getting the current location

MyLocation class for getting location changes,

```
public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    public boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

To receive the location updates override the `gotLocation()` method which will give you a data once there's a location change.

```
MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult() {
                        @Override
                        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                            //Got the location!


                        }
                    };

                    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
                    myLocation.getLocation(getActivity(), locationResult);
```