# Retrieving location every 5 seconds

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

Hi I am creating a project. It is about tracking a driver. The driver must send his location every 5 seconds to the Firebase. My problem is how do the passenger retrieve the location of the driver every 5 seconds too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good way of getting the user's location in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android)

Comment: If your driver sends the location to the Firebase Database, any connected passengers will automatically receive that location. See the Firebase documentation on how to retrieve data from the database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
LocationRequest locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationrequest.setInterval(5000);   // 5 seconds
LocationClient locationclient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, this);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

In this link, it is suggested that you use the new `Google Play services location APIs`. But they have the same idea.