# Do I need a google maps api key in order to get the users GPS location data?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My android app does not use or need to display a map.  I just want to pull the GPS location data every second or so.  I'm attempting to implement google play services in order to grab the users location.  I keep running into tutorials with deprecated lines.  I'd rather not start out a new app with deprecated lines built in.

I'd possibly accept as an answer to this question, a fully explained from scratch tutorial.

Comment: Hi.. Please check this link [link](http://www.androhub.com/introduction-to-android-google-maps-v2/).

Comment: I am pretty newbie to android development. But I made a "GPS" class some time ago that fetch device location without Maps Api key. Hope this helps: https://gist.github.com/xxnoobmanxx/e809093c0f0bd90e89c86857f823fd9d

Comment: Kumar, your page seems to be an example of using google maps api key.  I was trying to clarify that you don't need to if you're not using maps.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up essentially coming up with my own solution and posting it on this other question.  But I think it's a little bit buried.  The problem we are now having on stackoverflow is that, over time, old correct answers become old wrong/depcrecated answers.

[Good way of getting the user's location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android/48586767#48586767)

The short answer is no, you don't need a google maps API key if you're getting just the location.

Comment: Nice research and development. I "plused" one you there. Thank you.